# recursion Calling C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hello All Stackoverflow programmers ,i'm a beginner Programmer, i'd like to know how this code work if you want please :)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hassn hassn = new Hassn();
          Console.WriteLine(Hassn.Factorial(5));
        }
    }
    class Hassn
    {
    public static double Factorial(double val)
        {
            if (val <= 0) return 1;
            return val* Factorial(val - 1); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function

Comment: thank you Steve for Help,but  I do not speak English well.If you can explain to me this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming languages use a 'call-stack' to keep track of which functions are being called and what values they contain. Each time `Factorial` is called, it is added, along with its variable values, to the stack. This is called the context. So the call-stack will look something like:

```
Factorial(5)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * Factorial(2)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * Factorial(2) * Factorial(1)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * Factorial(2) * Factorial(1) * Factorial(0)
```

At this stage, val == 0 so 1 will be returned from the call to Factorial(0). This context is now 'popped' from the call-stack and the value returned is used in the next context to calculate the value (in this case 1*1), which is then returned to the next context (2*(1*1)):

```
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * Factorial(2) * Factorial(1) * 1
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * Factorial(2) * (1 * 1)
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * Factorial(3) * (2 * (1 * 1))
Factorial(5) * Factorial(4)  * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))
Factorial(5) * (4  * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1))))
(5 * (4  * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))))
```

This is a very general explanation and I just wanted to provide you with an alternative. Just try to understand that each call to `Factorial` is nested within the previous call and then all the return values have to be combined to get the final result.

Comment: Yes actually this answer that I need it ,thank you very much, Can you recommend a particular book or Article to read about stack

Comment: Any book on data structures will contain information about stacks as they are used for many different things in programming. Google 'stack data structure' and there are lots of resources which will explain it for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
Factorial(5) ->
5 * Factorial(4) ->
5 * 4 * Factorial(3) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * Factorial(2) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * Factorial(1) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * Factorial(0) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

Comment: thank you Jakub Lortz,I know very well that the process has in this way But I expect that the function will return the value 1 According condition  if (val <= 0) return 1;

Comment: @NourAhmed It returns 1 when `val <= 0`. Otherwise, it returns `val` multiplied by `Factorial(val - 1)`